# Retrieving the selected items from a multi-select ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sdk-2.3, multiple-select

I am currently implementing a multi-select `ListView` for my android app. My aim is to retrieve the selected items from the `ArrayAdapter` associated with the `ListView` when clicking the search button.

I am currently stumped on how to do this, I have found stuff online such as trying to set a `MultiChoiceModeListener`, but this does not seem to come up as an option in `Eclipse`. I am using `Google API`s(level 10), `Android 2.3.3` equivalent. Here is the code I have so far:

```
   public class FindPlace extends Activity {    

    public FindPlace() {}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_places);
        Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories);
        ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,categories);
        final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);
        list.setAdapter(ad);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { }

        });     
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method [`getCheckedItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more efficiently / correctly:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); ++i)
{
    if (checked.valueAt(i))
    {
        int pos = checked.keyAt(i);
        doSomethingWith(adapter.getItem(pos));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take the count of the selected item in the int and make for loop like below.

```
int len = listView.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
if (checked.get(i)) {
       String item = cont_list.get(i);
       /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
   }
}
```