# Getting all Listview checked Indexes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Retrieving the selected items from a multi-select ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653319/retrieving-the-selected-items-from-a-multi-select-listview)

I'm using a `ListView` with mode `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.

Is there a way to get the indexes of all checked Items ? In the question I posted above, there's a suggestion to use the method `getCheckedItemPositions()`, but I don't want to iterate over the entire list and check if it returns true so this is not what I need. I want to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
int[] checkedPositions = list.getCheckedIndexes();
for(int index : checkedPositions)
{
   list.remove(index);
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all checked items from a ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

It may use less code if such a method exists to return an array of checked items, but that method would likely use the same time complexity as just iterating yourself.

Comment: Not necessarily.. they might maintain a list while checking and unchecking list items. I can do it myself but just to know if they might have something like that already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getCheckedItemIds` as mentioned in the documentation :

> Returns the set of checked items ids.

To make it works correctly , in the adapter `getItemId` make it returns the position of the item